# Как правильно csrftoken от django в angular2?

Tags: python, django, angular2

Доброго времени суток,

Переписываю проект с angular (роутинг был на стороне backend) на angular 2
На стороне backend стоит django. Написал роутинг, аутентификацию по средством записи в куки (использовал для этого пакет angular2-cookie).
Ранее, для того чтобы просто забрать csrftoken, чтобы спокойно писать код, использовал своего рода небольшой костыль:

```
let token = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)csrftoken\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

Но теперь этот вариант не работает, а как правильно работать с csrftoken django - angular2 не могу в полной мере разобраться.

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь поможет в этой сложившейся ситуации. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит посмотреть сюда: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

Your server may use a different cookie or header name for this purpose. An Angular application can customize cookie and header names by providing its own CookieXSRFStrategy values.

```
{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name') }
```